# Is it possible to call a method from another class with incorrect number of arguements in Java?

Tags: java

I have 2 java class as separate java files say, `Class A` and `Class B`

Class A had a method called `Method A(1,2)` with 2 parameters.

```
Class A(){
    Method A(1,2)
}
```

`Class B` creates an object of `Class A` and try to access `Method A` with no parameters.

```
Class B(){
    A a = new A()
    a.Method A()
}
```

Is this case possible? If so how can I implement this in Java!

Comment: Won't compile. You need an overload with the number (and types) of the provided arguments.

Comment: Why do you want to call a method without params?

Comment: I am writing a selenium web driver test script wherein I require to call different class files from a single file after meeting some entry criteria. It would be great if I call a java file directly from a single class. Is there any such way?

Comment: Why do you want to test things that aren't possible?

Comment: If you use reflection you can make it compile but you will get an exception when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option would be to send null values or string literals, or use String ... notation (if the arguments are strings).

Answer (score 2):

You can define a java method to accept any number of parameters using the "varargs" syntax, for example

```
public void myMethod(String... s) {
    // s is an array String[]
}
```

If present, a varargs parameter must the last parameter.

These are all valid ways of calling this method:

```
myMethod(); // in this case the parameter is not null - it's an empty array
myMethod("foo");
myMethod("foo", "bar");
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot call a method with the wrong number of parameters. In fact it shouldn't even compile. Either provide an overload with no parameters or provide default values.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't call `methodA()` with no args on a `classA` reference, because `classA` simply doesn't have `methodA()` with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A(){
   Method A(){
       return Method A(1,2);
   }

   Method A(1,2){
      ...
   }

}
```

add a method with no parameters, which calls the 2 param method with default values.

hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He wants to call a method with the wrong number of parameters.

Comment: "Is this case possible? If so how can I implement this in Java!" I think it answer for the question

Comment: You have not demonstrated calling a method with an incorrect number of arguments. You have demonstrated calling a method with the *correct* number of arguments.